# AWS cognito callback can't read url params

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, url, amazon-cognito, urlsearchparams

I'm using AWS cognito hosted UI , after signing in I get redirected to the callback URL I configured with the id_token in the url , the problem is that there's a '#' character before the idtoken ( http://exmple.com/callback#id_token=eyJra ) and this '#' is not allowing me to read the idtoken for some reason .

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution , # is used for refrencing html elements in page , we can use location.href to get full url